# using hidden fields a good idea? (ASP.NET, C#)

Tags: c#, asp.net, hiddenfield

In an application, I draw some data from a database which will be used by several methods. Is it a good idea to write the data to hidden fields when first drawn or should I draw the data again when needed?

Comment: What is a hidden field in C#?

Comment: This question does not contain enough information. Add technology (WPF, ASP, SL, ...) Add the amount of data. Add the number of times it should be redrawn/evaluated. Show code you already wrote.

Comment: @Rolfcoptr: I think the OP might mean `private`.

Comment: @Roflcoptr, it might be a hidden input on an ASP.NET page... ;)

Comment: @RoflCoptr, @Emo - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hiddenfield.aspx

Comment: @Roflcoptr, @Erno: It should be ASP.NET, judging from his previous posts.

Comment: Are you trying to access this value across postbacks or something?

Comment: Wow, well, I couldn't have been more wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what the data is and how you're going to use it.

**What kind of data is it?**

If it's data that should be secured, such as PHI or other, never store it this way. Use session state. Otherwise, go to the next question below.

**Where will you use it?**

If it's used in the code behind, use viewstate or session state. If you plan to consume it using jquery or javascript and it doesn't need to be secured, a hidden field is fine.

Answer (score 3):

It depends **what you are trying to save** or hold.

- Privacy

  If the data needs more security then don't save it in hidden fields.
- Size

  If the data is small then its fine else hidden field is not efficient way.

Answer (score 1):

I say it depends on your need for security. Remember hidden fields are client-side and therefore editable by the end user.

If these fields are going to be posted back or used for anything more sensitive than a bit of interaction, then it may be safer to grab it from the database each time.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean a private field, then yes, that's a good idea as long as the data is the same for all of the methods using it.

Answer (score 0):

This depends, I suppose, on a couple of factors that would include, but not be limited to:

- How often does the data change?
- How often will you need to hit the DB if always getting the data afresh?
- How sensitive is the data being retrieved?
- How much data is being retrieved?
- So on and so forth...

For the most part, the decision is purely down to circumstance; and we don't necessarily have the circumstantial information.

Answer (score 0):

Hidden field means you send those data to the client and the client uploads the data back to you on submit. It may be a security or a performance problem. **But it all depends on your scenario.**

You may want to rather use a [Session](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx)

Or [Caching](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xsbfdd8c%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

It is usually a good idea to have single source of truth, the 'master' for your data. Now you may want to replicate this data for performance reasons, but until you need it, you shouldn't.